# CMake and Qt5 AUTOMOC error

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5, moc, automocking

I have a project which uses Qt5 and I have a `CMakeLists.txt` file that I use for creating the Visual Studio Solution.

This is an excerpt of my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_policy(SET CMP0020 NEW)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS core widgets)

set(COMMON_INCLUDE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

include_directories( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${COMMON_INCLUDE_DIR}
)


file(GLOB_RECURSE COMMON_SOURCE "*.hpp" "*.cpp")
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${COMMON_SOURCE})
qt5_use_modules(${PROJECT_NAME} Widgets)
```

When I try to compile the code it returns the following error:

```
>AUTOMOC : error : C:/Users/.../Projects/MyProject/build/MyProjects_automoc.cpp The file includes the moc file "moc_MyFile.cpp", but could not find header "MyFile{.h,.hh,.h++,.hm,.hpp,.hxx,.in,.txx}" in C:/Users/.../Projects/MyProject/build/
```

The moc file have been auto-generated and the header is not in the build folder, but in a folder locate in the src directory.

How is possible to fix this error?

Comment: what version of CMake are you using?

Comment: is it working well if you put all files in dir where CMakeList.txt is located and 
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is good to add:

```
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
```

when using the `AUTOMOC` feature. Furthermore, this

```
include_directories(
  ...
  ${QT_USE_FILE}
  ...
)
```

is a mistake. It should rather be:

```
include(${QT_USE_FILE})
```

Finally, you should only explicitly push sources to compilation, but **not** headers! As stated in the documentation:

- If `Q_OBJECT` is in the `foo.h` (i.e. `QObject` is declared in the header file),
  then in the corresponding `foo.cpp`
  don't forget to add `#include "moc_foo.cpp"`, preferably at the end
  of the file;
- If `Q_OBJECT` is in the `foo.cpp` (i.e. `QObject` is declared in the source file), 
  then, again, in the `foo.cpp` itself
  don't forget to add `#include "foo.moc"`, preferably at the end
  of the file.

Therefore, follow these recommendations and change

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE COMMON_SOURCE "*.hpp" "*.cpp")
```

to

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE COMMON_SOURCE "*.cpp")
```

You could also find **[my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16481750/1743860)** helpful. Your question is very similar, so I'd recommend to search better before posting next time.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, the first suggestion seems to work. Regarding the second I edited the question, I didn't include `${QT_USE_FILE}`, it was a copying error. Seems that `include(${QT_USE_FILE})` is also not necessary. `qt5_use_modules(${PROJECT_NAME} Widgets)` should take care of it. For the last suggestion I have to include all the sources, because I want to operate on them in Visual Studio.

Comment: However, having Q_OBJECT in a header should be enough to create moc files. CMake will behave in this way, too, if the header files are in the same folders as the source files. qmake will behave in this way with out-of-source headers, as well... this is just something CMake does not seem to support (talking of 3.9)

Comment: Adding moc_foo.cpp to every source you write seems WAY worse to me than adding header files as sources to CMake target. Ideally CMake should run AUTOMOC on files in include directories but this still does not seem to happen (CMake 3.15).

Comment: Agreed with @JanHošek. Although it would be better if CMake handled MOC for header files automatically, explicitly providing headers to the target is better than manually including moc sources. It seems CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR has no effect in this method.